# Data Studio Linking API and Calculated Fields

Tags: looker-studio

I am working with the Linking API and am finding that if I include ANY of the "ds." parameters in the URL, that the resulting data source loses all calculated fields from the original data source. Based on the documentation, it seems like we should be able specify *some* of the "ds." parameters, but as long as we don't specify ds.connector, it should still Update (which would keep the calculated fields?). But I'm finding that the only way to get the resulting data source to include calculated fields is to specify NONE of the ds. parameters. Any assistance would be so appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Data Studio, thanks for flagging it!

We aren't copying calculated fields or parameters from the original datasource unless `ds.<alias>.refreshFields` is false, and the default is true for Sheets and BigQuery datasources. I suspect that you're only seeing this when you add a "ds" parameter because when you don't have any "ds" parameters and your original data source is reusable, that original data source gets added to the new report instead of creating a new one.

We have a fix that should be going out in the release tomorrow (July 26, ~2pm PDT) but you can work around it in the meantime by adding either
`ds.<alias>.refreshFields=false` (to fix one datasource) or `ds.*.refreshFields=false` (to fix all datasources, if you have more than one).

Comment: THANK YOU, Alan! That is super helpful. I will add the 'false" parameter and check it out.

Comment: Has something changed with the way the Linking API works? We have been successfully using it to duplicate dashboards with embedded data sources that have parameters...but now the parameters disappear when duplicating.

Comment: This was a different bug where data source parameters weren't being preserved on datasource copy, which broke the Linking API because it makes data source copies when it creates the new report. We pushed the fix last night so everything should be working again.

Comment: Thanks, Alan! I appreciate you letting me know. Is there a better place for me to ask these questions or get these updates? Thanks.

Comment: We are having a lot of issues with parameters in embedded data sources disappearing when the data source is updated, not just related to the linking API.